# Suffered from vs suffered

Tags: conjunctions, rules

When should I use from?

Example:

His company suffered a setback.
Vs
His company suffered from a setback.

She suffered from a heart attack.
Vs
She suffered a heart attack

I realise that sometimes either is ok but are there any rules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use *suffer* with a direct object, you are generally referring to a single negative experience. For example:

> She suffered a heart attack on her 80th birthday.
>
> The company suffered a setback when its CEO resigned.

*Suffer from*, on the other hand, is generally used when referring to the continuing consequences of a negative event or experience:

> For the last few years of her life she suffered from a heart attack
>   that occurred on her 80th birthday.
>
> The company suffered from the setback until things picked up 5 years
>   ago.

The above are general principles for distinguishing the two terms, but there are counter examples in actual usage. For instance, this [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suffered%20poverty,%20suffered%20from%20poverty&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,suffered%20poverty;,c0;.t1;,suffered%20from%20poverty;,c0) shows "*suffered from poverty*" as the more usual phrase, but not significantly more common than "*suffered poverty*".

Comment: I had a feeling that it could be explained that way. Thanks Shoe.